# CSS transition property

Tags: css, transition

I've got three images in anchor tags within a div. I'm using CSS transitions to make it look pretty. I would like the images to be centred, I achieve this by using float:inline; But, when I use anything other than left or right, the transition ceases to work

This is the CSS

```
.previousvideos img {
    float: inline;
    margin-top: 15px;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
}
.previousvideos img:hover {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

This is the HTML/PHP

```
<div class="previousvideos">
<a href="<?php echo "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$latestvideo[1]['videoID']}"; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $latestvideo[1]['thumbnail']; ?>" width="300" height="169">
</a>
<a href="<?php echo "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$latestvideo[2]['videoID']}"; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $latestvideo[2]['thumbnail']; ?>" width="300" height="169">
</a>
<a href="<?php echo "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$latestvideo[3]['videoID']}"; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $latestvideo[3]['thumbnail']; ?>" width="300" height="169">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `inline` is not a valid value for `float`. Please set up a JSfiddle clearly demonstrating your issue.

Comment: You can have a gander at my site here: [link](http://80.4.38.130/GiggleSquid_Website/) The prblem is the three thumbnails at the bottom

Comment: Your margins are collapsing on the spacer element above it. You shouldn't be animating with `margin`, make the container bigger and use `position:relative` and then animate on `top`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [***this***](http://jsfiddle.net/h52zJ/) is what you were looking for, then it works for me.

**CSS**

```
.previousvideos img {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
}
.previousvideos img:hover {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

#### EDIT

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h52zJ/2/)

Comment: His problem only occurs when the images are **not** floated. Which is correct because a floated element is taken out of flow layout, and thus its margins can't collapse because there's nothing to collapse to.

Comment: Floating left or right works fine. But, is there a way to center the three images?

Comment: If you don't float, then you can use `text-align` to center them, as they are in `a` which is an `inline` element. If you float them, then you can reduce width of `.previousVideos` and use `margin: 0 auto`. Added a new Fiddle based on @NielsKeurentjes advice